# word automation problem

Tags: c#, word-automation

I am trying open a word document for manipulation. However in the code below 'wordApp.Selection' is always null

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
 Word._Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word._Document aDoc =wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fPath1, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

Word.Selection selection = wordApp.Selection
```

Any ideas on how what I am missing here. Why is wordApp.Selection getting set as null.?

Thanks.

Comment: got it!!

had to add the line:
aDoc.Activate();
before the line
Word.Selection selection = wordApp.Selection

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to set the selection before it will have a value -- when you open a document in Word, it does not automatically select the entire document, you would have to do that programmatically before Selection has a value.

Comment: how? I cant see any examples anywhere that explain that.